# Get Fragment page title that is determined at Runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` that contains two Fragments. Two Fragments extends from AbstractFragment which extends Fragment. I am not able to get the page title of the fragment when its created because the title is pass as an argument to the fragment:

 FragmentActivity's inner Class:

```
ArrayList<AbstractFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<AbstractFragment >();
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return fragments.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return fragments.size();


    }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                return fragments.get(position).getTitle();

            }

        }
```

AbstractFragment :

```
protected Bundle data;
    protected String title;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        data=this.getArguments();
        numberSetData=data.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_CHART_DATA);
        title=data.getString(KEY_CHART_TITLE);
        //Title should is determined here.
    }
public abstract String getTitle();
```

ConcreteFragment:

```
@Override
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
```

[image]

The problem solves if I swipe to the next fragment , title will appear but not when its created. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getTitle` at a point where `onCreate` has not yet been called for that `Fragment`. A known workaround for this would be to check if `onCreate` has been called, and if not then return `data.getString(KEY_CHART_TITLE)`.

```
public String getTitle()
{
    if( title == null )
    {
        title = getArguments().getString(KEY_CHART_TITLE);
    }
    return title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it works. Didn't think it was that simple. I keep thinking I should get the adapter from activity and manually calling it again. Thanks.